# Redirect entire site to a sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I am trying to redirect my entire site to a subfolder present in the root directory using the following Redirect command.

`Redirect 301 / http://example.com/folder/`

However, when I open the website, it gets redirected to something like 
`http://www.example.com/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder...`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're redirecting anything starting with `/` so of course that includes `/folder/` and it just keeps redirecting. You can't redirect your whole site to a part of itself without excluding that part.

Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

It will redirect anything that is not in `/folder/`.

To only redirect the homepage, use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /folder/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do I add this in the .conf file, or the .htacess in the root directory?

Comment: Okay, this is working in the .conf file. But I'm getting `http://example.com/folder//` with a double `//` at the end. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you asked for it in .htaccess :) (your post is tagged .htaccess) Main config is better though. I updated the rule for that. Clear your cache to see new result.

Comment: This works. Thanks! But what if I only want the main URL to redirect to the folder subdirectory. I assume this redirects everything that is not /folder?

Comment: Yes, the entire site as you asked in your question. I added information for how to redirect the homepage only.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my answer. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: That's not possible, you need to clear your browser cache, it must be cached. In Firefox you can "forget this site" or try another browser.